# Most efficient way to order an Array created from a HashSet

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

I am working on a method that creates a HashSet of bus stops within a certain radius of a given GPS coordinate and then converts this set into an Array.

I would like to order this Array by distance relative to the GPS coordinate, which would be the most efficient way to do that?

```
public Stop[] possibleStops(GPSCoordinate spot) {
    Set<Stop> viableBusStops = new HashSet<Stop>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Stop> stopEntry : stops.entrySet()) {
        Stop applicant = stopEntry.getValue();
        Double distance = spot.distance(applicant.getGPSCoordinate());
        if (distance<=threshold) {
            viableBusStops.add(applicant);
        }
    }
    Stop[] stopList = viableBusStops.toArray(new Stop[0])
    return stopList;
}
```

Edit:
The challange is that the "distance" **is not** an attribute of the Stop object. I was wondering if I can sort those bus stops calculating the distance only once.

Comment: use the built in Collections.sort method

Comment: Create a `StopDistance` type with attributes `stop` and `distance` and store that instead of `Stop` instances in the temporary collection. Sort accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this method: [Arrays.sort with Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))

Note: that you should probably cache the calculated distance to the desired spot within the `Stop` object (or a wrapper) so that this logic is not executed multiple times during sorting when comparing objects with `Comparator`

You also may consider to use `TreeMap` where `key` is a distance and `value` is a `Stop` - and then extract values and convert them to an array.

Comment: actually `TreeMap` with a distance as `key` is a bad idea, since you will run into the issues if multiple stops have the same distance to the `spot`

Answer (score 1):

Build a `Map<Stop, Double>` that maps the stops against their distance from the point. Then sort the entries based on the distances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 Streams for that:

```
public Stop[] possibleStops(GPSCoordinate spot) {
    // dummies
    Map<String, Stop> stops = new HashMap<>();
    double threshold = 10.0;

    Stop[] filteredSortedStops = stops.values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap((stop) -> stop,
                    (stop) -> spot.distance(stop.getGPSCoordinate())))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter((entry) -> entry.getValue() <= threshold)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .toArray(Stop[]::new);

    return filteredSortedStops;
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, but I think the terminal operation is wrong. Maybe you should add a `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` before `.toArray(Stop[]::new)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Treeset with Comparator?

```
public class SortByDistance implements Comparator<Distance>{
        public int compare(Distance d1, Distance d2) {
            return d1.getLength().compareTo(d2.getLength());
        }
    }

TreeSet<Distance> names = new TreeSet<Distance>(new SortByDistance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public Stop[] possibleStops(GPSCoordinate spot) {
    return stops.values().stream()
        .map(stop -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
            spot.distance(stop.getGPSCoordinate()), stop))
        .filter(e -> e.getKey() <= threshold)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey()))
        .map(Entry::getValue)
        .toArray(Stop[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a function that takes a bus stop as an argument and returns its distance to the spot, you could create a comparator that sorts bus stops based on their distance to the spot, as returned by the function.

However, in order to do its job, a comparator might access one given element more than once, meaning that for a given bus stop, its distance to the spot might end up being calculated more than once.

One way to avoid this is by using a technique called [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). In essence, this implies the use of some kind of cache to remember previously calculated values for the function.

You can achieve memoization with the following helper method:

```
static <T, R> Function<T, R> memoize(Function<T, R> function) {
    Map<T, R> cache = new HashMap<>();
    return t -> cache.computeIfAbsent(t, function);
}
```

Now, to solve your problem, you could create a memoized function that takes one bus stop as an argument and returns its distance to the spot:

```
Function<Stop, Double> distanceToSpot = memoize(busStop -> 
    spot.distance(busStop.getGPSCoordinate()));
```

Then, declare a `Comparator<Stop>` as follows:

```
Comparator<Stop> byDistanceToSpot = Comparator.comparing(distanceToSpot);
```

Finally, use this comparator to sort your collection of bus stops:

```
Stop[] viableBusStops = stops.values().stream()
    .filter(busStop -> distanceToSpot.apply(busStop) <= threshold)
    .sorted(byDistanceToSpot) // only sort bus stops within threshold
    .toArray(Stop[]::new);
```